# Is this geometrically-defined minimum an algebraic number?

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-optimization

I'm trying to find the maximum value $c$ so that there is a probability distribution with support in $R_c:=[-2,2]\times[-2,2]\cap\{x+y\geq c\}$ so that $32$ expectational equations hold.  In particular, I want $\mathbb{E}(x^ay^b)$ with this distribution to agree with the same expectation on the distribution with density $\sqrt{4-x^2}\cdot\sqrt{4-y^2}/(4\pi^2)$, for the pairs $(a, b)$ with $0\leq a, b\leq 4$ and also where either $a$ or $b$ is $0$ and the other is between $5$ and $8$.  So in other words, I want random variables $X$ and $Y$ with support on $R_c$ so that

$$E(X)=E(Y)=E(X^2-1)=\cdots=E(X^8-14)=E(Y^8-14)=0$$

and there's 32 expectations in that chain.

My strategy is to fix $c$ and look at the convex hull of the image of $R_c$ under the map $(x, y)\rightarrow (x, y, x^2-1, xy, \ldots y^8-14)$ and ask when it contains the origin.  I can then use techniques of Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi to detect this.  If so, I can construct specific points whose convex hull contains the origin and use linear algebra to find an explicit probability distribution; if not, I can find a hyperplane separating the two, meaning a polynomial $P(x,y)$ so that $P(x,y)>0$ for all points in $R_c$, but integrating against $\sqrt{4-x^2}\cdot\sqrt{4-y^2}/(4\pi^2)$ to be a negative number, which proves the impossibility of such a distribution on $R_c$.  I then basically binary-search to find the optimal $c$.  This all works well, and I have come up with the following:

The points

```
(0.40233388785758,−0.68162727157206),(−0.68162490825764,0.40233317377632),(−0.03593446385013,1.4223373527278),(−0.58181793464029,1.65045045907013),(0.59759350821447,−1.78077844166752),(1.53829446803677,1.53829443533382),(−1.48621983094263,1.99140650840038),(1.42233731135369,−0.03593490350603),(0.05438775487699,0.05438886977203),(−1.78077900893326,0.59759354704086),(1.99140617335252,−1.4862186561741),(−1.40798021804983,−1.06840257328206),(0.59759347905152,−1.78077910495742),(−1.48621965507992,1.99140661320125),(1.12294676572784,1.12294624842174),(1.42233869303903,−0.03593747650892),(1.65045062298356,−0.58181827821828),(0.40233336753712,−0.6816247052117),(−0.68162690245729,0.40233386944888),(0.40233322519093,−0.681625459605),(1.12294556005286,1.12294583096732),(−0.03593985561373,1.42233955543634),(−0.58181951983038,1.65045131684197),(1.99140650540332,−1.48621961266743),(1.65045237751894,−0.58182231464692),(−1.78077877657724,0.59759334939547),(−1.06840211927449,−1.4079806720575),(1.53829124404177,1.53829176844063),(−1.40797805061751,−1.06840474071448),(1.9914061436234,−1.48622121985896),(0.59759450830252,−1.7807799162483),(−1.4862239646326,1.99140795748714),(−1.40798623761224,−1.06839655371975)
```

give a point-mass probability distribution for $c=−2.4763827913320$, and the polynomial

```
−9.6430622783853(x+y)+108.9702541224326(x*y)+49.2216326267277(x^2+y^2)−180.0171980017891(x+y)(x*y)+125.0609266454326(x*y)^2−9.225013979636(x^3+y^3)+6.9445854923998(x^2+y^2)(x*y)+68.1838852970187(x+y)(x*y)^2−66.0585984730189(x*y)^3−11.7940568488902(x^4+y^4)+49.3497768306(x^3+y^3)(x*y)−48.7776655621495(x^2+y^2)(x*y)^2+9.217112694634(x+y)(x*y)^3+(x*y)^4−10.4048835085938(x^5+y^5)−3.4018229998967(x^6+y^6)+4.1057063608821(x^7+y^7)+1.7252053549918(x^8+y^8)
```

has minimum of $−0.495177804465548$ on $R_c$ where $c=−2.4763827913319$, but whose expectation is $−0.4951778044674$.

Anyway, so the optimal value for $c$ is somewhere between $−2.4763827913320$ and $−2.4763827913319$.  My question is: is this value of $c$ algebraic?  I'm 99.9% sure it is, since most everything is defined algebraically and the only usage of "real" feels like it can be replaced with algebraic conditions like the limiting function $P$ has $13$ critical points all of whose value at the function itself is also $0$, and $c$ is just the sum of the coordinates of the points on $P=0$ that have a slope $-1$ tangent curve.  But I don't know how to formalize all this information into a single algebraic equation.

Comment: Would you be able to break the question into sections? Ideally, a self-contained question at the top, then background & motivation, your work, perhaps references, etc.

Comment: If $X$ is uniformly distributed among $0,0,1,1,0.471,0.877,1.366,1.773$, where the last four numbers are the four positive roots of $3−20x^2+33x^4−18x^6+3x^8=0$, then the distribution of $(\pm X_1, \pm X_2)$ agrees with the specified distribution on all the specified moments. This suggests to me that algebraic numbers of degree 8 might be enough.

Answer (score 8):

By [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)), if the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{32}$ is contained in the convex hull of the set
$$
X_c = \{\,(x, y, x^2 - 1, \ldots, y^8 - 14) \mid -2 \le x, y \le 2, x + y \ge c\,\}
$$
then there exist some 33 points in $X_c$ whose convex hull contains the origin. Thus, your question is equivalent to: Find the maximum value of $c$ such that:

($*$) there exist $(x_1, y_1)$, ..., $(x_{33}, y_{33})$, $a_1$, ..., $a_{33}$ such that: (i) $a_i \ge 0$ for each $i$; (ii) $a_1 + \cdots + a_{33} = 1$; (iii) for each $i$, $-2 \le x_i \le 2$, $-2 \le y_i \le 2$, and $x_i + y_i \ge c$; (iv) $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_{33} x_{33} = 0$, ..., $a_1 (y_1^8 - 14) + \cdots + a_{33} (y_{33}^8 - 14) = 0$.

The statement ($*$) is a first-order statement in the language of an ordered field, so by Tarski-Seidenberg, the maximum $c$ which satisfies ($*$) is indeed an algebraic number. Now, how large the degree of its minimal polynomial might be, I won't begin to speculate...

Comment: This is the answer I was sort of expecting in my head, though I'd never heard of Tarski-Seidenberg before.  I'll wait to see if anyone has any more insight into the details of the problem, but I'll accept this answer if not.

Comment: Are you implying that the proof of T-S doesn’t use the structure of the reals? Or that if a sentence that is defined in a small model is true in a bigger model, then it’s true in the smaller model as well? I’m not a logician, so that sounds like a true theorem but I don’t know its name.